# SQL Injection on MariaDB

Tags: sql-injection, mariadb

I am trying to exploit (legally) a MariaDb database with an SQLi vulnerability.

I have identified the vulnerability here...

`/?o=1&page=app`

The `o=*` is vulnerable and produces the following error...

`DEBUG INFO: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5' or dest like '1'') LIMIT 10' at line 1`

I am using Burp Suite and have landed upon the following syntax which seems to be closer to the mark but is still producing a syntax error.

I think it is closer to the mark because the error is only spitting out the query that I have introduced and not the 'extra' field: `'5' or dest like '1'') LIMIT 10'`.

I am assuming that is part of the original query as the `1` is included and when I test with other random strings that remains true.

I am after the admin password hash which I know from the page clues is `uid 1`.

What am I missing with this query?

`SELECT Password FROM mysql.user WHERE (uid = '1' or dest like '%') --') LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space after your comment marker.

> From a '-- ' to the end of a line. The space after the two dashes is required (as in MySQL).

[Comment syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/comment-syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without more details, but possible the number from UID is not enclosed within quotes:

```
SELECT Password FROM mysql.user WHERE uid = 1 ...
```

Unlike strings, numbers do not necessarily have to be within quotes.

Comment: Good point but doesn't seem to affect the result...
`DEBUG INFO: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Password FROM mysql.user WHERE (uid = 1 or dest like '%') --') LIMIT 10')' at line 1`